# Separate Kendo Scheduler Editor Templates

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, scheduler

Am I able to load a custom template based on a condition?

eg..

If I was making a booking for a mechanic then the editor form would show textboxes for carmodel, yearmake etc.

If I was making a booking for a carpet cleaner the editor form would show textboxes for howmanyrooms, room sizes etc..

Am I able to pass an ID of a service and show the particular editor form for the correct service?

we can currently display this functionality if we create different scheduler Views but that would then create a duplication of many pages.

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution for this problem? Can you share them?

Comment: No I didn't but I did find a work around by dynamically adding textboxes on the following page. To b able to choose a view model at runtime for the scheduler didn't seem possible

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and after searching a long time and combining what I found, I came to this :

1) above my scheduler I have a kendodropdownlist

```
<input id="reservationPicker" />
<script>
$("#reservationPicker").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "reservationDefTypeId",
    dataSource: reservationPickerDataSource
});
</script>
```

2) my event has an extra field reservationDef which will hold the information of the dropdownlist.

3) I can use this information in my template

```
<script id="editorScheduler" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<center>
    <div id="main">
        #if(reservationDef=="mechanic"){#
            <h3>Mechanic stuff</h3>
        #}else if(reservationDef=="carpetCleaner"){#
            <h3>Carpet Cleaner stuff</h3>
        #}else{#
            <h3>unknown type of reservation !</h3>
            #: reservationDef #
        #}#
    </div>
</center>
</script>
```

4) I use this template in my scheduler

```
editable: {
template: $("#editorScheduler").html()
},
```

5) but what with a new appointment ! I use the add event of the scheduler and I fill in this information in the event

```
add: function (e) {
var reservationTypes = $("#reservationPicker").data("kendoDropDownList");
var selectedReservationType = reservationTypes.dataItem();
e.event.reservationDef = selectedReservationType.appointmentTitle;
},
```

This does the trick for me. Good luck !

Comment: thats good stuff. If i see right you are going to be making the appointments for the "Carpet cleaner /  merchanic"?? .. So when you aim to save the editor fields into the db, the seperation of fields needs to be checked. lets say the carpet cleaner needs to know room size and number or rooms, but the merchanic needs to collect car model and engine size... The viewmodel would be huge to try and compensate all the required fields for a given category/subcategory.. To then save additional table fieds there would be one massive table with many rows. Otherwize save the data into the Title row.

Answer (score 0):

No I didn't but I did find a work around by dynamically adding textboxes on the following page. To b able to choose a view model at runtime for the scheduler didn't seem possible

if anyone knows how to load a particular viewmodel at runtime using mvc would be very intresting for future ideas and development.